# "docker exec" and "docker start" fails to find container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm new to docker and created an image from a repository that includes a "**dockerfile**". 
The build process ended successfully generating an image ID of 295e7c040cc2.
When I try to run "`docker exec -it 295e7c040cc2 /bin/bash`", I get an error:

```
Error: No such container: 295e7c040cc2
```

Running "docker images" shows that the image exists.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your image

```
docker run -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash 295e7c040cc2
```

---

`docker run` is a wrapper for `docker create` and `docker start` and instantiates a new container from your image and starts it for you.

`docker exec`, on the other hand, executes the specified code in a running container.

---

More info can be found here

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/
- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/

Answer (score 0):

`295e7c040cc2` is docker image ID , it's not container ID.
First create container from docker image.

More reference:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/
- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/